# insertBefore отрабатывает только с первым элементом итерации

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь спецов! Просидел пять часов, перепробовал много всяких вариантов, но решения так и не нашел.

```js
let text = document.createTextNode('link: ');
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(text);
        
let parNodes = document.querySelectorAll('p > a');
for (let i = 0; i < parNodes.length; i++) {
  console.log(parNodes[i].parentElement);
  parNodes[i].parentElement.insertBefore(span, parNodes[i])
};
```

```html
<p><a href="http://www.google.be" name="google">www.google.be</a></p>    
<p><a href="http://www.hbvl.be" name="hbvl">www.hbvl.com</a></p>
```

По задумке текст "Link" должен добавляться перед каждой ссылкой, но у меня `insertBefore` срабатывает только на одной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы создаёте элемент вне цикла, а потом вставляете один и тот же элемент в цикле — и он не дублируется, оно просто берётся из одного места и перемещается в другое, и оказывается в конце только у последнего элемента. Создавайте и вставляйте в цикле:

```js
let parNodes = document.querySelectorAll('p > a');
for (let i = 0; i < parNodes.length; i++) {
  let text = document.createTextNode('link: ');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(text);
  console.log(parNodes[i].parentElement);
  parNodes[i].parentElement.insertBefore(span, parNodes[i])
};
```

```html
<p><a href="http://www.google.be" name="google">www.google.be</a></p>    
<p><a href="http://www.hbvl.be" name="hbvl">www.hbvl.com</a></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!!!! Моей радости нет предела!!!

Comment: @AdamOrs Выражением и апофеозом Вашей радости может стать щелчок по значку "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: Попытался это сделать, но к сожалению рейтинг не позволяет.

Comment: @AdamOrs Не стрелки "вверх/вниз", а *знак "галочка"* под ними.

Comment: @AdamOrs Молодец!

Comment: Понял. Первый день на сервисе )

Comment: Спасибо) Удачного продолжения) Только не пишите больше «срочно» — это обычно считается нарушением этикета (читающим кажется, что их взяли за горло :) ) и вопрос могут заминусовать.